# Task :react-native-async-storage_async-storage:copyReleaseJniLibsProjectAndLocalJars FAILED

Tags: android, react-native, gradle

```
* What went wrong:
A problem was found with the configuration of task ':react-native-async-storage_async-storage:copyReleaseJniLibsProjectAndLocalJars' (type 'LibraryJniLibsTask').
  - Gradle detected a problem with the following location: '/Users/admin/Desktop/WorkOnProjects/PartnerApp-new/node_modules/@react-native-async-storage/async-storage/android/build/intermediates/stripped_native_libs/release/out'.
    
    Reason: Task ':react-native-async-storage_async-storage:copyReleaseJniLibsProjectAndLocalJars' uses this output of task ':@react-native-async-storage_async-storage:stripReleaseDebugSymbols' without declaring an explicit or implicit dependency. This can lead to incorrect results being produced, depending on what order the tasks are executed.
    
    Possible solutions:
      1. Declare task ':@react-native-async-storage_async-storage:stripReleaseDebugSymbols' as an input of ':react-native-async-storage_async-storage:copyReleaseJniLibsProjectAndLocalJars'.
      2. Declare an explicit dependency on ':@react-native-async-storage_async-storage:stripReleaseDebugSymbols' from ':react-native-async-storage_async-storage:copyReleaseJniLibsProjectAndLocalJars' using Task#dependsOn.
      3. Declare an explicit dependency on ':@react-native-async-storage_async-storage:stripReleaseDebugSymbols' from ':react-native-async-storage_async-storage:copyReleaseJniLibsProjectAndLocalJars' using Task#mustRunAfter.
    
    For more information, please refer to https://docs.gradle.org/8.3/userguide/validation_problems.html#implicit_dependency in the Gradle documentation.
```

deps and dev deps

```
"dependencies": {
    "@miblanchard/react-native-slider": "^2.3.1",
    "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "1.21.0",
    "@react-native-community/datetimepicker": "^7.6.2",
    "@react-native-community/netinfo": "^11.3.0",
    "@react-native-community/push-notification-ios": "^1.11.0",
    "@react-native-firebase/analytics": "^18.8.0",
    "@react-native-firebase/app": "^18.8.0",
    "@react-native-firebase/messaging": "^18.8.0",
    "@react-native-google-signin/google-signin": "^11.0.0",
    "@react-native-masked-view/masked-view": "^0.3.1",
    "@react-native-picker/picker": "^2.6.1",
    "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^6.5.12",
    "@react-navigation/drawer": "^6.6.7",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.1.10",
    "@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.9.18",
    "@reduxjs/toolkit": "^1.9.5",
    "axios": "^0.27.2",
    "moment": "^2.29.3",
    "num-words": "^1.2.2",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-native": "^0.73.0",
    "react-native-biometrics": "^2.2.2",
    "react-native-blob-util": "^0.19.6",
    "react-native-chart-kit": "^6.12.0",
    "react-native-circular-progress": "^1.3.9",
    "react-native-circular-progress-indicator": "^4.4.2",
    "react-native-contacts": "^7.0.8",
    "react-native-document-picker": "^9.1.1",
    "react-native-dotenv": "^3.4.10",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^2.15.0",
    "react-native-image-picker": "^7.1.0",
    "react-native-image-slider-box": "^2.0.7",
    "react-native-linear-gradient": "^2.8.3",
    "react-native-maps": "^1.10.3",
    "react-native-modal": "^13.0.0",
    "react-native-modal-datetime-picker": "^17.1.0",
    "react-native-otp-verify": "^1.1.8",
    "react-native-pdf": "^6.7.4",
    "react-native-push-notification": "^8.1.1",
    "react-native-reanimated": "^3.7.0",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^4.9.0",
    "react-native-screens": "^3.29.0",
    "react-native-share": "^10.0.2",
    "react-native-skeleton-placeholder": "^5.2.4",
    "react-native-sms-retriever": "^1.1.1",
    "react-native-snap-carousel": "^3.9.1",
    "react-native-splash-screen": "^3.3.0",
    "react-native-svg": "^14.1.0",
    "react-native-svg-transformer": "^1.3.0",
    "react-native-svg-uri": "^1.2.3",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^10.0.3",
    "react-native-walkthrough-tooltip": "^1.6.0",
    "react-native-webview": "^13.8.1",
    "react-native-youtube-iframe": "^2.3.0",
    "react-navigation": "^5.0.0",
    "react-navigation-stack": "^2.10.4",
    "react-redux": "^8.0.5",
    "to-words": "^3.3.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.20.0",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.20.0",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.20.0",
    "@react-native/babel-preset": "^0.73.0",
    "@react-native/eslint-config": "0.73.2",
    "@react-native/js-polyfills": "^0.74.0",
    "@react-native/metro-babel-transformer": "^0.73.15",
    "@react-native/metro-config": "^0.73.0",
    "@react-native/typescript-config": "0.73.1",
    "@rnx-kit/align-deps": "^2.3.4",
    "@types/react": "^18.2.6",
    "@types/react-test-renderer": "^18.0.0",
    "babel-jest": "^29.6.3",
    "eslint": "^8.19.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.33.2",
    "eslint-plugin-react-native": "^4.1.0",
    "jest": "^29.2.1",
    "metro-config": "^0.80.5",
    "metro-runtime": "^0.80.5",
    "prettier": "2.8.8",
    "react-test-renderer": "18.2.0",
    "typescript": "5.0.4"
  },
```

Kindly help in finding a solution

Working fine in npx react-native run-android but ./gradlew assembleRelease throwing the error

Answer (score 0):

- The error you're facing is likely due to a misconfiguration in your Android build. When you run npx react-native run-android, it uses the debug build variant, which doesn't require signing. However, when you run ./gradlew assembleRelease, it uses the release build variant, which requires signing.
- Task :react-native-async-storage_async-storage:generateDebugRFile FAILED : [Task :react-native-async-storage_async-storage:generateDebugRFile FAILED](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74333132/task-react-native-async-storage-async-storagegeneratedebugrfile-failed)
- React Native Android build failure with different errors without any changes in code for past days due to publish of React Native version 0.71.0-rc.0 : [React Native Android build failure with different errors without any changes in code for past days due to publish of React Native version 0.71.0-rc.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74334162/react-native-android-build-failure-with-different-errors-without-any-changes-in)
- Error when trying to build gradle in latest version #995 : https://github.com/react-native-async-storage/async-storage/issues/995
- Execution failed for task ':react-native-async-storage_async-storage:extractReleaseAnnotations #906 : https://github.com/react-native-async-storage/async-storage/issues/906
- You need to declare an explicit dependency between the two tasks. You can do this by adding the following line to your build.gradle file:

  dependencies {
  task ':react-native-async-storage_async-storage:copyReleaseJniLibsProjectAndLocalJars' dependsOn ':@react-native-async-storage_async-storage:stripReleaseDebugSymbols'
  }
- This will ensure that the :react-native-async-storage_async-storage:copyReleaseJniLibsProjectAndLocalJars task is always executed after the :@react-native-async-storage_async-storage:stripReleaseDebugSymbols task, which will prevent the error from occurring.
- Publishing to Google Play Store : https://reactnative.dev/docs/signed-apk-android

Answer (score 0):

try to run this command ./gradlew app:assembleRelease